# Is my proof correct? Sequences in normed vector spces

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

**Question:** Assume the vector space $X$ has two norms $||\cdot||_a$ and $||\cdot||_b$. Assume $\exists C>0$ such that $||x||_a \leq C\cdot||x||_b$ for $\forall x\in X$ and that the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converges to $x$ in the $||\cdot||_a$ norm and converges to $y$ in the $||\cdot||_b$ norm. Show that $x=y$.

**My proof (idea):** We have that $\forall\varepsilon>0 \ \exists N\in \mathbb N$ such that for $n \geq N$ we have that $||x_n-y||_b<\varepsilon$. Now, using the inequality given to us in the question we have that $||x_n - y||_a < C\cdot\varepsilon$. Defining $\varepsilon' := C\cdot\varepsilon$ we have that, using the proper definiton of convergence in a normed vector space with $\varepsilon'$ and $N$ as before, $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converges to $y$ in the $||\cdot||_a$ norm. However, the limit of a sequence with a given norm is unique, which means that $x=y$.

Is this proof correct or have I made a fundamental error along the way?

Comment: You could put it shorter $||x_n - y||_a < C\cdot || x_n - y ||_b \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and use uniqueness of the limit

Comment: Cheers. But nothing wrong with my proof?

Comment: Formally you should start the other way around. For any $\epsilon >0$ there is a $N(\frac{\epsilon}{C})$ etc.